# How to give different content to every td in the table

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling giving different content (icons in my case) to every `<td>` using `nth-chid()` method.

If I'm adding this CSS rule, I see on every `<td>` one type of icon:

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget td:before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "\e04f";
    position: absolute;
}
```

At this stage, I want to overwrite the rule above, but I see no changes, all icons are the same.

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget td:before:nth-child(1) {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "\e04e"!important;
}
```

If I give the `!important` rule, shouldn't overwrite the rule above?

PS: How to overwrite the rule when I will get to second row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not with the `important`.

Your selector is wrong. `:before` should be used at the end of selector.

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget td:nth-child(1):before {
```

First select the first child element and then use `before` on it.

Comment: works fine now, but the changes are applying to all the column, is there a way to change in every cell? so that the icons can be different?

Comment: would you be so kind and read the last sentence? PS: How to overwrite the rule when I will get to second row?

Comment: @VadimBadea I misunderstood it, well you can use `nth-child(2)` and so on for each of the td element

Comment: Yes, but it applies for the entire column. But what I want to do is to change the content for every `td` cell, the content is different for each of those.
I have 3 rows, 3 columns

Comment: @VadimBadea Can you please create jsfiddle demo, it'll be easier for both of us to solve problem quickly

Comment: So just to clarify, what I want to do, is to set content arrows in the top row center cell, middle row left cell, middle row right cell, bottom row center cell.

Comment: @VadimBadea Please check https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/gz7fc4hL/5/. Update the arrow content values

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the pseudo-class `nth-child` first before the `::before` pseudo-element.

Your code had the logic of `Select the first before pseudo-element of the parent` Pseudo elements are fake and not part of the DOM, so they are not calculated using nth-child.

Below code makes a logic `Select the before pseudo-element of td which is first child of the parent`

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget td:nth-child(1):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "\e04e";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply :nth-child before :before like

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget td:nth-child(1):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "\e04e";
}
```